# Git bash on windows 7. mysqldump command is not working

Tags: php, mysql, git

I'm using git bash on a windows 7 machine. When I try to use mysqldump I'm getting an error:
"sh.exe": mysqldump: command not found". I am very new to this. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you actually have MySQL installed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need `mysqldump` on the path that bash is using to find commands. UN*X shells, like bash, and also windows cmd, use a `PATH` environment variable to manage this.

To see your current path, type this in bash:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If you've installed MySQL, it's typically located at `c:\Program Files\MySql`, and the support programs, like `mysqldump`, are in `c:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\`. You'll need to have that directory on your path. If MySQL has been installed somewhere else on your machine then you'll need to find the `bin` directory there and use *that* path in these instructions.

The best way to do this in windows is by changing the user or system environment variables. To do this, in Windows Explorer:

- Right-click `Computer` and select `Properties` from the menu.
- In the resulting window, choose `Advanced System Settings` in the sidebar.
- In the resulting dialog, click the `Advanced` tab.
- Near the bottom, click the `Environment Variables` button.
- There are 2 sections, `user` at the top, and `system` below. Either will work, but let's change the `system` settings.
- Scroll the list until you see the variable named `Path` in the `Variable` column.
- Double-click this `Path` row.
- In the resulting dialog, in the `Variable value` field, scroll all the way to the end of the field, and at the end, add this: `;c:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.5/bin/`. **Note the leading semicolon**: it won't work without it.
- Click `OK` and now you can close all the dialogs/windows.

Once you've done all that, close the Git bash window, and open another one. Type:

```
$ mysqldump
```

You should get Usage instructions from the program.

If not, look at the path again by typing:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Do you see anything like what you added? Any MySQL directories there? It's likely you've just mistyped something, or missed the semicolon. Go over the steps again and make sure everything is correct.

Comment: pb2q, Thanks for the detailed instructions. I finally got it to work.