# Why might vim think that $HOME is the U:\ drive?

Tags: vim, windows-7

When I run `echo $HOME` `gvim` reports that `$HOME` is `U:\`, and when I exit it tries to write to the drive, and it can't, because...I don't have a U: drive.  I get the error `Can't write viminfo file U:\_viminfo`

Comment: what is the value of HOME **outside** vim? type: `echo %HOME%` in a cmd/DOS window.

Comment: That ENV variable doesn't exist...when I echo %HOME% I get %HOME% back.

Comment: Try `echo %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` in a cmd/dos window.

Comment: Ah and there it is...U:\ I still don't know why it's U:\, maybe I'll have to talk to the system admin.

Comment: check your system environment variables, you can change %HOMEDRIVE% there system-wide or per-user. Perhaps some old environment config left laying around? I recently posted instructions on changing environment variables in an unrelated answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801941/git-bash-on-windows-7-mysqldump-command-is-not-working/11802118#11802118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here.

Windows Network policies in my office were mapping automatically a shared network with the Z: drive, and adding it as the homedrive. 
The mapping worked correctly in the command line, and some applications used it with no problem. Others don't.

Later I found that those problematic applications were the ones running with administrator permissions. Looks like drive mappings are user-dependent. 
Running Vim as a normal user solved the problem.