# how to start Mysql in git bash in windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, git, wampserver

hi i want to know there is anyway to start Mysql in Wampserver in git bash Program with command line 
like `$ Mysql start`

Comment: Try lowercase `mysql start`, or `mysql.server start`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/automatic-start.html

Comment: it said sh.exe" : mysql : command not found

Comment: Is the `mysql` executable in your path? try `where mysql` in the command line and note the output.

Comment: it said "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)"

Comment: RE: @rmorrin - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11802118/2317532)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mysql executable is likely not present in your path, so will not be found when you try to execute from any CLI.

Follow the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html), adjusting for the version of mysql you have installed.

Comment: my databases i made before with phpmyadmin is not there when i using "show databases ;"

Comment: Glad to hear it - That'll need to be a separate question if you can't solve it yourself!

Comment: @alirezavalipour Are you sure you're logged in as the right user? You will only have access to databases that you have permissions for.

Comment: @rmorrin the path for my mysql executable is `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin` . I tried the steps still no luck