# MySQL can't be accessed through the terminal

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, path, command

When I try to use MySQL on my terminal I get an error. I've already tried editing my Path environment variable but it still won't work.

$ mysql -u

=>sh.exe": mysql: command not found

Please help

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602002/how-to-start-mysql-in-git-bash-in-windows-8-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't access mysql from command line mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac)

Comment: If your path was set correctly it would work. Find out where `mysql.exe` is and make sure the directory it's in is present in your `PATH`.

Comment: It works on command prompt but doesn't work on gitbash.